# Facebook app public but only accessible to developers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, devise

My FB app is public (green dot) and is working perfectly fine for admins and developers. However, authentication fails when a non user tries to login.

FB app screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XviGr.jpg

Interestingly, non-developer users are able to reach the permissions screen, but are not able to login using FB. I am using only the approved permissions:
scope: 'email, public_profile, user_friends, user_birthday'

I am on rails + devise + omniauth + omniauth-facebook.

In code, it redirects to OmniauthCallbacksController#failure. I tried creating failure action to see what's happening, but it is not giving me any message. Not sure how to debug this.

I am using following:

```
gem 'devise', '3.4.1'
gem 'omniauth', '1.2.2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '2.0.0'
```

Here is what I see in production.log:

```
I, [2015-05-01T17:55:39.141944 #2341]  INFO -- : Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 122.167.223.121 at 2015-05-01 17:55:39 +0000
I, [2015-05-01T17:55:39.706464 #2341]  INFO -- : Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQC5ypphUjqzOquyD4HMWFvaCZjvMfahg5Y_...fljWMCh&state=0857ab97a79206c582b2b7b5391d99cda7b5d4e5ba2f730e" for 122.167.223.121 at 2015-05-01 17:55:39 +0000
I, [2015-05-01T17:55:41.231336 #2341]  INFO -- : Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
I, [2015-05-01T17:55:41.231394 #2341]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"code"=>"AQC5ypphUjqzOquyD4HMWFvaCZjvMfahg5Y...MCh", "state"=>"0857ab97a79206c582b2b7b5391d99cda7b5d4e5ba2f730e"}
I, [2015-05-01T17:55:41.232699 #2341]  INFO -- : Redirected to http://www.oyelife.com/
I, [2015-05-01T17:55:41.232832 #2341]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean " but are not able to login using FB"? did it sue to work? what happens when they enter their username and password? more information so we can help you

Comment: Well, after user enters username and password, it comes back to login page (homepage) without user being logged in (callback URL of my website is not called). It works fine if the user is one of the developers (or admin).

Comment: are you sure the email they are using to log in is not already in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out myself after more tinkering.

Seems like callback URL must also be listed in **Settings > Advanced > OAuth Settings > Valid OAuth redirect URIs**. It works without it for developers, but is required for public.

Would be better if Facebook mentions this somewhere.